# The Pfieffer Vacuum Protocol for RS485

Tags: rs485, modbus

i am working on a control Interface for serveral Components including turbo Pumps from the company Pfeiffer.

The communication will be done according to the The Pfieffer Vacuum Protocol for RS485.

Does any one have experience with this Protokoll or is there a library that can be used for this art of communication.

I will use a MAXCHIPRS485 for the communication between Arduino (SerialPorts) and the Pumps RS485 Port.

the Wiring is clear .
I want to ask if someone already has done a similar Code that sends and reads from the Pump continuously.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please ask a question that is about an Arduino